# SQL Sum and Group By need to retrieve more than 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

If using the SUM function and Group By statement i am only able to display 2 columns.

Need to select more columns to display from the table.

For example i would like the output to display the Customer,Total Quantity,CustomerName,CustomerAddress

Customer Table:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Customer  |OrderQuantity |CustomerName|CustomerAddress|
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Mike      |5             |Smith       |123 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Sally     |6             |Smithon     |124 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Sally     |4             |Smithon     |124 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Mike      |2             |Smith       |123 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

Current SQL statement:

```
select customer,SUM(order_quantity) as total_quantity
from smr.dbo.tdpb_recall_manual_entry m
group by
customer
```

Current Result:

```
+----------+--------------+
|Customer  |OrderQuantity |
+----------+--------------+
|Mike      |7             |
+----------+--------------+
|Sally     |10            |
+----------+--------------+
```

Desired Result:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Customer  |OrderQuantity |CustomerName|CustomerAddress|
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Mike      |7             |Smith       |123 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
|Sally     |10            |Smithon     |124 Main St.   |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

in the desired result you

Comment: **Do NOT** tag-spam every DBMS.

Comment: Judging from the `dbo.` stuff in the question, this is a [sql-server] question, not a [mysql] question (not that the answer's much different).  Fixing the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name and address data is same for a given customer, just include the columns in group by and select.

```
select customer,
    CustomerName,
    CustomerAddress,
    SUM(order_quantity) as total_quantity
from smr.dbo.tdpb_recall_manual_entry m
group by customer,
    CustomerName,
    CustomerAddress
```

If not, you can, maybe, use `MAX` function to get one of them:

```
select customer,
    SUM(order_quantity) as total_quantity,
    max(CustomerName) customerName,
    max(CustomerAddress) CustomerAddress
from smr.dbo.tdpb_recall_manual_entry m
group by customer
```

Also, note that your table is not fully normalized. You should have a separate `customer` table with customer id and details and an `orders` table with customer id as foreign key from the customer table and order_quantity.

Answer (score 0):

when you write order of selecting customers, just write what you need as a result.
the selext statement selects the columns so,
just query this.
select customer,SUM(order_quantity) as "total quantity ",CustomerName,CustomerAddress from...... and then the rest of it. to get the desired result.

remember always to put what you want from the query. in the starting of select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Make your query like this,
Add all the columns you want to view in the `SELECT` clause and then group the columns which dont have analytical functions applied.

```
select customer,SUM(order_quantity) as total_quantity, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
from smr.dbo.tdpb_recall_manual_entry m
group by
customer, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
```